# Cakephp - checkPasswords is always false

Tags: cakephp, model, passwords

I'm working on the signup process and want to check if the two passwords (password + re-entered password) are equal. These are my validation rules in the User Model:

```
var $validate = array(
    'username' => array( 
            'notEmpty' => array( 
                    'rule' => array('minLength', 5), 
                    'required' => true, 
                    'allowEmpty' => false, 
                    'message' => 'User name has to be at least 5 characters long' 
                ),
        array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'User name taken. Use another'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
                'notEmpty' => array( 
                    'rule' => array('minLength', 6), 
                    'required' => true, 
                    'allowEmpty' => false, 
                    'message' => 'Password has to be at least 6 characters long'
        ),
        'password_similar' => array( 
                    'rule' => 'checkPasswords',
                    'message' => 'Entered passwords does not match' 
            )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => 'email',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email'
    )
);
```

In the `users_controller.php` I have the `checkPasswords` function:

```
function checkPasswords($data) { 
    if($data['password'] == $this->data['User']['password2hashed']) 
        return true; 
      else
        return false;    
}
```

An my singup function looks like this:

```
function signup(){ 
    if (!empty($this->data)) { 
        if(isset($this->data['User']['password2'])) 
               $this->data['User']['password2hashed'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password2']); 


     $this->User->create(); 

    if ($this->User->save($this->data)) { 
.
.
.
}
```

No matter what I do, the passwords do not match. Even if I change the `checkPasswords` function to this:

```
function checkPasswords($data) { 
    return true;
}
```

What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I just realised that the checkPasswords Function is not supposed to be in the controller but in the model. Problem solved, I'm ashamed...